# Delete multiple /n in php

Tags: php, regex, function

I'm working on a old database, and i'm trying to clear the multiple /n on the text fields.

I have found this code :

```
   $newphrase = preg_replace("#\n+#", "\n", $newphrase);
```

It's works, but I want to replace /n only when there is more than 3 /n, not two.

So, my goal is to transform :

```
Hello n/ guys /n /n how are /n /n /n you ?
```

into

```
Hello n/ guys /n /n how are /n /n you ?
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: why do you switch around / and \ ? also: `{3,}`

Comment: So you want to replace more than 3 `\n` with 2 or 1 `\n`?

Comment: Are there also spaces between the newlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newphrase = preg_replace("#(\n ?){3,}#", "\n\n", $newphrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean `/n` and not `\n` (newline), then go with:

```
$newphrase = preg_replace("/(?:\/n\x20?){3,}/", "\/n\x20\/n\x20", $newphrase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing 3 or more  blank lines with 1 blank line -

Find:
`\n(?:[^\S\n]*\n){2,}`
Replace:
`\n`